# macOS change chrome default geolocation?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

By mistake, Chrome set my default location and search domain to Romania. How to change it back on macOS. I know this is possible because I have done it before. I just forgot to properly record how I did it so I know how to again...

Comment: Is this a problem on Google Search Enigne or on Google Chrome?

Comment: @gioalexiou Chrome